# SQL retrieval from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

`Sales` table

```
ItemID  Date               Code
-------------------------------------------------
12345   2019-02-17          1
12345   2019-02-17          2
12345   2019-02-17          3
-------------------------------------------------
12344   2019-02-18          1
12344   2019-02-18          3
12344   2019-02-18          2
-------------------------------------------------
12443   2019-02-19          1
12443   2019-02-19          2
12443   2019-02-19          3
```

I want to retrieve those item ids from `Sales` table where Code 2 is updated after code 3. So my query should return `12344` as result... I cannot think of any functions to achieve this as I have limited knowledge on SQL. Can someone please provide me some suggestion on achieving this? Thanks

Comment: what order by do you use in the sales table

Comment: Actually I want to display the sixth row entirely in result as for Item ID 12344 is having code 2 updated after 3 while others are in order like 1,2,3

Comment: @Abhijit . . . The dates are all the same.  What are you using for ordering?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "natural ordering".

Comment: @GordonLinoff I actually want to display in results itemId 12344 as Code 2 is updated after code 3 in db... So does date matter here? I am not aware that much in this context... In results date can be ignored, only itemId I want to display...

Comment: @Abhijit: You don't understand what Gordon is saying. Tables contain **unordered** rows. You have three rows for itemid 12344 and you say that code 3 comes before code 2. What makes you say so? What rule does apply here to consider one row before the other?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that you are looking for

```
select sales1.itemId from sales sales1 
       inner join sales sales2 
       on sales1.itemId = sales2.itemId 
       where sales1.date > sales2.date and sales1.code = 2 and sales2.code = 3;
```

Check if it helps you.

Comment: Actually those dashed lines in tables are for understanding only.... I want the result along with all columns...

Answer (score 0):

You can include a column

> update_seq_no

Each time you update you can increase the update_seq_no and then you can achieve your requirement you want using the below sql.

```
alter table sales add (update_seq_no number);

create SEQUENCE  IFSQ_UPDATE_SEQNO  MINVALUE 1000 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 NOCYCLE ;
  -- for existing rows (just a work around) 
 BEGIN  
 for rec in (select rowid row_id,itemid,date from sales where  update_Seq_no is null order by 2,3 asc)
  loop
  update sales set update_Seq_no=IFSQ_UPDATE_SEQNO.NEXTVAL
  where rowid=rec.row_id;
  commit;
 end loop;
 end;
 --for new rows  
 insert into sales values(p_itemid,p_date,3,IFSQ_UPDATE_SEQNO.NEXTVAL);
 insert into sales values(p_itemid,p_date,2,IFSQ_UPDATE_SEQNO.NEXTVAL);


with sales1 as (select row_num1,a.* from (select rownum row_num1,b.* 
from sales b order by update_seq_no asc)a)
select a.*
from sales1 a,sales1 b
where a.row_num1-1=b.row_num1
and a.code=2 and b.code=3
and a.itemid=b.itemid
and a.Date=b.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using lag()

```
select itemid from
(
select sales1.itemId,sales1.code,
sales1.code-lag(code) over(partition by itemid order by dates) as diff
from sales sales1 
where code in (2,3)
)A where diff>=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one row per itemid and code, then you can simply aggregate:

```
select itemid
from mytable
group by itemid
having max(case when code = 2 then date end) > max(case when code = 3 then date end);
```

With your sample data, however, no itemid will be returned, as all codes per itemid have the same date. None comes before the other.